# Which letters do not appear consecutively in English words?

Tags: orthography

Are there any letters in the English alphabet that ***never*** appear twice ***consecutively*** in a word?

For example: the word *ru**nn**ing* has the letter *n* repeated consecutively in it.

What letters never appear in such way (for example *q* comes to mind)?

---

<sup>For context, this is asked in relation to *"breaking"* encrypted messages. Knowing about such letters can help rule out some of the options.</sup>

Comment: This article would seem related: [Which double letters appear most frequently in English text?](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2014/10/03/double-letter-bigrams.html) - especially the section on _The frequency of double letters in an English corpus_ which mentions "Some double letters did not appear in the corpus: JJ, KK, QQ, VV, WW, and YY. "

Comment: You're new here and also got immediately downvoted for what seems to be a reasonalbe question. Seems like this substack has problems. Mods should really look in to this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I consider it is on the trivia side of the dividing line, being more appropriately asked on Puzzling.SE. Questions on ELU focus on English usage, and should always be accompanied by reasonable research and attempts at answering. Requests for lists are almost always considered off-topic.

Comment: @KillingTime _Bookkeeper, trekking_ and _sawwort_ were obviously not included.

Answer (score 5):

If I calculate the number of occurrences of double letters in the (about 90 000 words) Mathematica online dictionary (which is not an authoritative dictionary of English because it contains some entries that are proper names), I find the statistics below:

> [Mathematica online](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DictionaryLookup.html)

In this table, the best candidates are ***qq*** and ***xx***, which both score zero (*xx* appears once in *Exxon*, which is a trade name).

The next is ***yy*** with *Omayyad*, *Ayyubid* and the proper name *Khayyam*).

Then we have ***jj***, with various words related to *hajj*

The subsequent more frequent occurrences are more likely to be found in conventional English dictionaries, where other words may also occur (note doxxing, in [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dox))

[image]

Comment: Doxxing is a word now.

Comment: @Damila yes, language evolves and dictionaries always lag behind. Dox is not in the Mathematica dictionary but is defined in merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dox. I have added your point to the answer.